# Laravel, command to commit contents of database to github, and command to hydrate database from repo

Tags: git, laravel, github, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I am new to Larvel, and am absolutely loving it. Using 5.4. When I commit, it is not comiting the contents of my MySQL database to Github.

I want to do this, because, when I go to another computer, I want to `git clone` then push the database so my setup is exactly the same.

So in summary, is there (1) a command commit the database contents to my Github repo, and then after this (2) a way to rehydrtate the database contents from my Github repo?

Comment: Laravel provides a simpler way to commit your database in Github, that is Migration. Create your database using Migration,you can push it with your code,and can pull from anywhere. https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/migrations

Comment: @molagbal - thanks but i need to commit the data of the database.

Comment: You should either look into Laravel database seeders to bring your database to a consistent state in new environments, or look into a remotely accessible central database that you can access wherever you need. Otherwise, you're probably looking at figuring out how to script a mysql dump on push and mysql load on pull, which... good luck.